# How to Open new toad session in already running toad through Commad line?

Tags: oracle, command-line, exe, toad

I have a requirement to connect to toad using command line, I am currently able to login to toad using

toad.exe -c username/password@server:port/Database

But when I try to connect to another database using the same command it calls the .exe again and opens another toad window, I want toad to open in same window in separate tab.

Please guide if I should use any Parameter/switch to open new connection in already running toad

Comment: TOAD is a GUI. Why don't you connect to another user as most of us do every day, many times a day - establishing a connection through TOAD's "New connection" menu item?

Comment: @Littlefoot I know the options from GUI is available , But I want to know which commend runs when we select new connection,  Its our requirement to connect through CMD.

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry.

Comment: Why not run your command to open a second instance of Toad?

Comment: @EJEgyed because we have to connect to multiple databases at a time and opening multiple instances of toad is not user friendly and it causes confusion and also more memory consumption..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Toad is already running, unless you find some way to run a command against the existing process, I don't think what you are trying to do is possible.

If you are just trying to create two database connections when Toad is initially launched, you can use a command like this:

```
toad.exe -c username1/password1@server1:port1/Database1 -c username2/password2@server2:port2/Database2
```